# Dealing with verb tenses in LUIS

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I have a LUIS app with some intents and I noticed that if i do not provide a certain intent with all tenses of a verb in the example utterances, it will not recognize a user utterance with a different tense.

For example if I have an intent called "upgrade service" which includes example utterances such as "I want to upgrade my service" and "i'm calling about upgrading my service", it will not recognize the user utterance: "i want my service upgraded" that well because the tense "upgraded" does not appear in the example utterances. If I add the example utterance "service upgraded" everything will work fine.

My question is: why do I have to provide the intent with example utterances of every possible combination of a verb tense, why can't you just give a single example utterance with a certain tense and LUIS takes care of the tense variations by itself? Isn't it a basic practice in language understanding to stem utterances before recognition to remove the tense and normalize the sentence? I saw the same behavior with plurals (if the intent only has the word "service" in the example utterances and sees the word "services" in the user utterance it will not recognize it).

Is there a way within LUIS to solve this in an elegant way (without duplicating utterances with every possible combination)? maybe phrase lists?

Comment: LUIS certainly has the ability to recognize utterances that use different tenses. However, it learns primarily based on what you train it to recognize. It is always recommended you provide more examples, not less, so it can fully anticipate what a user may say. Without fully training your app confidence scores may be less stable than you would prefer as the app is left to guess. This, in turn, may affect overall results. Testing will answer this, but providing some examples of different tenses may be enough and save you from entering a host of them. But, I would recommend being thorough.

Comment: But the documentation states that LUIS learns best from few utterances with lots of variations (word choice, word order, word count, etc.):
"LUIS builds effective models with utterances that are selected carefully. Adding too many utterances is not valuable because it introduces confusion." (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-utterance#add-small-groups-of-10-15-utterances-for-each-authoring-iteration).
The documentation recommends that improvements come from phrase lists, patterns and active learning (reviewing endpoint utterances) instead

Comment: Essentially, that is what I'm say. But, you still want many variations for the utterances you include. With too few examples, it also can't be effective.